# Service running AsyncTask over and over in onCreate() method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a Service that i run when a alarm is sent.

The problem is the service runs ever couple of hours automatically.

I only want it to run once when the alarm is executed.

Here is the code i am using:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
   loadList service_release = new loadList();
    service_release.execute();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return startId;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
        loadList service_release = new loadList();
    service_release.execute();
            }
```

Someone told me i should move the AsyncTask to execute in onStartCommand(). But i didnt see anything in the docs that will fix my problem by doing this.

What do i need to do for it to run once and dont kepp running over and over throughout a time period after the alarm is set off?

EDIT:

My Alarm is being set up like this..

```
String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(alarm);

Intent Aintent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Aintent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.FRIDAY, );
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 4 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use an `AsyncTask` in a `Service` - `AsyncTask` is primarily designed to work in a UI context. Also `onStart(...)` is deprecated and you should be using `onStartCommand(...)` instead. That aside, however, you haven't given enough information - if the `AsyncTask` is being run over and over, then that suggests the `Service` is being started over and over. Without knowing how the 'alarm' is being setup / triggered (and perhaps what your `AsyncTask` looks like) it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a repeating alarm, that means it will be triggered *repeatedly*, and launch the service each time it is. If you don't need it to repeat, set a non-repeating alarm, using `AlarmManager.set()`.

Comment: I want it to repeat every 4 days

Comment: Maybe you have some old alarms. Run `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to check what's registered. Also you `setRepeating()` call looks wrong: the first parameter is 'triggerAtTime', the second 'interval', what you have will trigger the first alarm _after_ 4 days, an repeat each day after that.